# Not all udp sent packets on localhost are displayed on wireshark

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, wireshark

I'm writing a simple udp traffic generator using C++ and PracticalSocket as socket wrapper (http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/) and I'm using Wireshark to check the output.
The issue is that all packets are sent without errors, but I didn't received all packets on wireshark.
Example: I sent 10000 packets without errors, but Wireshark displays 9876 packets only.
This is the SENDER code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PracticalSocket.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
const int PAYLOAD_SIZE = 1464;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char txBuffer[PAYLOAD_SIZE];
    string destAddress = argv[1];
    unsigned short destPort =  atoi(argv[2]);
    unsigned long numOfPackets =  atoi(argv[3]);
    UDPSocket tx_sock;
    unsigned long int i;
    printf("START\n");
    int ret;
    unsigned long int errors=0;
    for(i=0;i<numOfPackets;i++)
    {
        ret=tx_sock.sendTo(txBuffer, PAYLOAD_SIZE, destAddress, destPort);
        if(ret<=0) {
            errors++;
            printf("ERROR\n");
        }

    }
    printf("END - packets(%d) errors(%d)\n",i,errors);
    return i;
}
```

The input and output in the terminal is:

udpGen 127.0.0.1 1234 10000

START

END - packets(10000) errors(0)

Then I wrote a receiver utility to check if the issue is WS.

```
#include "PracticalSocket.h"

using namespace std;
const int BUFFERSIZE = 1500;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned short rxLocalPort = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned long int maxCounter = atoi(argv[2]);;
    UDPSocket rx_sock(rxLocalPort);
    char echoBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];         // Buffer for echo string
    int recvMsgSize;                  // Size of received message
    string sourceAddress;             // Address of datagram source
    unsigned short sourcePort;        // Port of datagram source
    unsigned long int counter = 0;
    printf("rx from port %d\n",rxLocalPort);
    bool go=true;
    while(go)
    {
        recvMsgSize = rx_sock.recvFrom(echoBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, sourceAddress, sourcePort);
        counter++;
        if(counter>=maxCounter){
            go=false;
        }
    }
    printf("received %d packets\n",counter);
    return 0;
}
```

From the command line I passed 1234 as destPort and 10000 as numOfPackets.
The application didn't exit from the while loop and so didn't print nothing. It returns only if I pass a greater value of packets to the sender application (i.e 11000).

Then I tried also to increase the tx and rx buffers on both sides, but with no effects. To do that, I added a member function to the UDPSocket class:

```
void UDPSocket::setbufferSize(int sndbuf, int rcvbuf) {
    int s = sndbuf;
    int r = rcvbuf;
    setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (raw_type *)&s, sizeof(s));
    setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (raw_type *)&r, sizeof(r));
}
```

Comment: Well, UDP is a lossy protocol. It's allowed for packets to be lost, or arrive out of order, or for one packet to be received more than once.

Comment: ok, but I sent 10000 packets to the localhost address. Why did WS capture less packets? I'm trying to figure out if all packets were really sent or no.

Comment: How are you capturing the packets to begin with? Wireshark doesn't usually capture localhost traffic by default, you have to take extra measures to enable that, such as installing Microsoft's loopback adapter and capturing on that. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: And just FYI, the code you have shown should not compile, because `UDPSocket::sendTo()` does not return an `int`, it returns a `void`.  It throws a `SocketException` if the send fails.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the loopback adapter. I tried also to write a simple receiver that counts the rx packets, but the number of the received packet is less than the number of the sent packets. I modified the original UDPSocket to return an int instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @Marco Please [edit] your question to show your receiver code. For all we know, the receiver has a bug in it, and the sender is fine. It is also possible that since you are sending to localhost, you are simply sending too many packets too fast, and you are overflowing the receiver's inbound buffer, causing packets to be discarded. UDP allows for that to happen.

Comment: I modified the question and I inserted the receiver code too. My goal is to send packets as fast as I can. I want to write a data acquisition software simulator to test my data collecting software.

Comment: @Marco I'm sticking with my earlier comment. You are likely sending faster than you can receive, so packets are getting dropped. There is no way to detect that condition in code, but there is a way to help avoid it from happening - you can increase the size of the receiver's inbound buffer so it can hold more packets before `recvFrom()` reads them. Use `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)` for that. But you will have to do it manually as `UDPSocket` does not implement that call for you.

Comment: Done, but no changes.

Comment: Try using `tcpdump` in order to capture packets

Comment: My project will be multi platform, but now I'm testing on Windows. I tried with command line tool tshark, but no changes.

Comment: @Marco: So how much packets gets your receiver application? Does it get more packets than wireshark? And note that WS not only has to capture the packets but also to display them, i.e. it might not be able to catch up with everything and thus loose packets. Better use something which only captures the packets into a file and does nothing else.

Comment: If I add a 5 milliseconds delay after the sendto it works: I receive the same number of packets that I transmit. With a delay lower than 5 milliseconds I don't receive all packets.

Comment: I need to transmit at a higher rate, about 1400 packets (1500 bytes) per second. So ((1400*1500)/(1024*1024))*8 is 2Mbit per second. I think that couldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Marco all the more reason to suspect that the receiver's inbound buffer is filling up and discarding packets. You didn't say how large you are setting the buffers to after adding `setBufferSize()`. And did you try using `getsockopt()` to verify the sizes are actually getting applied?

Comment: I added the getsockopt() call and it's ok. I tried with 4000000, 16000000 and 32000000 buffer sizes: increasing the size I'm getting better result, but not 100%.

Comment: On Linux it works !